# Cann't open folders on bootable usb under linux Mint 19

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I had an usb.This usb I made as bootable linux mint.Now if I try open usb I can not open my usb like disk/I can see only bootable folders. If i connect usb to the computer I see next window[image]

How to open my folders, not systems?

Comment: Don’t just re-post [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448104/cannt-see-folders-on-boodable-usblinux-mint-19). It was closed because it was off-topic. What makes you think it isn’t still off-topic?!

Comment: I have a problem and try to find helps in the community and you close my post without chance to get answer?it's not good

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question. You could try asking on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), but be sure to read the rules _before_ posting.

Comment: You are wrong because this problem can be solved on programming and admin-level/Please don't close the question at least 1 week, thanks

Comment: I may be wrong, but then could you please clarify how this is programming-related? I can’t see any programming in the question, what kind of answer are you expecting that involves programming?

Comment: I would like to know is any bash scripts exists which can solve my problem.If you moderate questions please be human oriented at first and try to help people.I think it's a right rule

Answer (score 0):

> How to open my folders, not systems?

When you create a live bootable disk, the existing data is wiped off from the USB stick. If you are thinking that your old data still exists on the USB, it's not.

If you want to use your USB like before for storing data, then use USB Stick Formatter tool which comes with linux mint (cinnamon) or use some other third-party tool to format your usb stick. And to create a bootable usb again use USB Image Writer tool from linux mint or use something like [balenaetcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) which does the same thing